# Changing content dynamically in css

Tags: javascript, css

I have set overflow:scroll; so if the content size increases it adds scroll. Instead of that i need to reduce the % of content so it will exactly in the box. Is there any variable that i can set in css? Is there any other way to achieve it?

P.S. I am new to CSS.

Comment: What about a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)?

Comment: CSS can't measure and calculate, only declare rules. You'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try "overflow: auto;" This will add scroll when required else it won't.

By the way what are you asking???

Are you trying to fit in all the contents inside the box no matter how large it is without the scroll bars?

If that's what you are looking for then you need to change the font size according to the content you are going to insert in your box using javascript and changing the size at runtime.

Comment: exactly. overflow: auto will be better. And also specify width and height of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The exceeding content cant be reduced by CSS. So you will have to use Javascript.
Otherwise if you want to hide the exceeding content. You can do so by giving Overflow:hide; this will hide your exceeding content. That means it will display only the content which can come inside that particular div. So by not showing the exceeding content the other way it gets reduced.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kile says, CSS can't measure and calculate, only declare rules. You'll have to use javascript or server side to calculate the % of content to reduce. Maybe if you add the code or screenshot we can help you a little bit more

Once thing you can do is to use `overflow:hidden` but that doesn't reduce the content, it just hide the rest of the text larger that the parent div.